# Can't Fix Positioning in HTML/Markup

Tags: html, css, position

Just wanna ask for your help regarding my markup, I am trying to do exactly the same like this image:

http://prntscr.com/6wrpr3

Here's my markup:

```
<div id="two-box">
   <div class="wrapper clearfix">
      <div class="column blue">
         <div id="circle">
            <div id="content">
               <h2>PARALLAX</h2>
               <h1>Text</h1>
               <h2>ARE COOL!</h2>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column red">
         <div id="circle-red">
            <h2>LET IT</h2>
            <h1>Fade</h1>
            <h2>RIGHT NOW!</h2>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="carport">
   <div class="wrapper clearfix">
      <div id="starynight"></div>
      <div id="car"></div>
      <div id="road"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

ANd now for my CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1140px;
}
.two-box{
    width: 100%;
}

.column{
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px 0;
}

.blue{
    background-color: #3498db;
    float: left;


}

.red{
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    float: right;

}


#content{
    margin-top: 150px;
}

.column h2{
      color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      font-size: 3.5em;
      font-weight: 300;
      line-height: 1em;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
}


.column h1{
      color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Pacifico', sans-serif;
      font-size: 4.2em;
       line-height: 0em;
       text-align: center;
       border-top: 4px solid #fff;
       border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
       padding: 40px;
       margin: 0;

}


#circle{
    background-color: #3aa3e9;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#circle-red{
    background-color: #f25a4a;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}




#road{
    background: url('http://arubacontests.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/road.jpg') no-repeat center;
    width: 1020px;
    height: 145px;
    display: block;
}

#car{
    background: url('http://arubacontests.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/car.png') no-repeat center;
    width: 325px;
    height: 125;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
}


#starynight{
    background: url('http://arubacontests.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/starynight.jpg') no-repeat center;
    width: 1012px;
    height: 768px;
    display: block;
}
```

Here's the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVYRep):

Let me know if there are things on my markup and CSS that i need to fix or show me the actual codepen. Thanks!

Note: The main issue here is the positioning of elements. Let's say I want the text and circle to be align together and not have a padding. Similar thing with the background and the car image they wont just align at all.

Comment: You should be more specific, you can't just expect that people will write all the code for you, try for yourself and if you don't understand something or don't know how to do it, as I said be more specific.

Comment: Hi I am talking about the aligning of my codes. Let me just set up the CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/4kk1fyjg/

I basically set the `background-position to cover`, fixed the car `height` (missing px at the end) and set the `wrapper position to relative` so that the car should be absolute positioned according to the container.

let me know if this works as expected.

Not sure about the car position, but you can adjust the position changing the `right` or `left` property

**EDIT**

Here you are:
http://jsfiddle.net/4kk1fyjg/2/

Just wrap the content inside another div, set the circle position to relative, display as table, the new wrapping div as table-row and the #content as table-cell, then make the table cell vertically align in the middle and that should be it.

Comment: Almost close enough however the box I want the text and circle to be align together and not have a padding they must be altogether inside the circle similar to the example image. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You miss `<div id="content">` in circle-red.

Remove width from `#starnight` and add `background-size: 100%` do the same for `#road`.

To `#car` change position to `relative` and add:

```
float:right;
bottom:100px;
right:150px;
```

To `#content` remove `margin-top` and add `padding-top:125px;`

And finaly for `.column h1` change margin to `margin: 0 40px;`

hope this work how expected

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aafLz05x/1/)